# C# (Windows Phone) Facebook get info

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, sdk

How do I get other info from the user like location, birthday, or gender? I'm using this code as a guide for the project that I'm doing. http://windowsphoneaalto.org/2012/01/facebook-get-information-about-the-user/

I was able to get the user's id and name but I can't get the other information. I tried getting the user's location by adding, string location = result["location"].ToString();

I ended up getting a null value and a keynotfoundexception. This is the piece of code that I'm having issues with.

```
void _fbClient_GetCompleted(object sender, FacebookApiEventArgs e)
    {
        //Turn the data into Dictionary.
        //If you want to see what the Facebook is returning you can check it
        //with this tool provided by Facebook
        //http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me
        var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
        //Get the ID value
        string id = result["id"].ToString();
        //Get the name value
        string name = result["name"].ToString();
        //Currently the thread running this code
        //is not the UI thread and only UI thread can update
        //UI. So we are calling the UI thread here.
        _page.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " (" + id + ")");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember you'll need to add that to the facebook apps extended permission and then ask the user to give you the rights to share those details.

Look more for extended permission on facebook will solve your problem